# Time-inhomogeneous Markov Chains

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am looking for resources to read about Time-inhomogeneous Markov Chains since most of the books and Youtube lectures focuses on Time-homogeneous Markov Chains. Thank you in advance.

Comment: next time use search function:-) https://mathoverflow.net/questions/168398/time-inhomogeneous-markov-chains

Comment: link to the book can be found on google